# Change this SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a query "change the number of publications on artificial intelligence over time." Can you help me change this query not only about artificial intelligence, but also about subclasses of artificial intelligence?

```
SELECT ?year (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q13442814 ;
        wdt:P921 wd:Q11660 ;
        wdt:P577 ?date .
  BIND(YEAR(?date) AS ?year)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
 GROUP BY ?year
 ORDER BY ?year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to replace `wdt:P921` with `wdt:P921/wdt:P279*` (see [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fyear%20%28COUNT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ13442814%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP921%20wd%3AQ11660%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20BIND%28YEAR%28%3Fdate%29%20AS%20%3Fyear%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fyear%0A%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fyear) for the new query).

`wdt:P921/wdt:P279*` is called *property path*. Such expressions are used for concatenating more properties in a single path which must comply with a certain structure. In this case, we are saying that the object of `wdt:P921` can be the subject of `wdt:P279` (`*` stands for "zero or more times") and the final object of such optional (chain of) `wdt:P279` must be `wd:Q11660`.

Check out [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language § 9 Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) for deepening this topic.